# Passwordless ssh using key authentication in rackspace cloud fails: asks for password

Tags: linux, authentication, ssh, public-key-encryption, rackspace-cloud

I am trying passwordless ssh connection using public and private key mechanism to a cloudserver(running redhat) in rackspace.

My commands are(in the server):

1. adduser  -g root
2. mkdir /home//.ssh
3. copy my public key to /home//.ssh/authorized_keys
4. chmod 700 /home//.ssh
5. chmod 600 /home//.ssh/authorized_keys

In the config file of server in the rackspace cloud:

1. RSAAuthentication yes
2. PubkeyAuthentication yes
3. #AuthorizedKeysFile     .ssh/authorized_keys

When I try to do "ssh -i my_priv_key @server_ip", it fails and asks me for the password of @server_ip.

When I added the following line to sshd_config on my server, it says Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).

Match User 
   PasswordAuthentication no

I have been trying for the last couple of hours but am not able to figure it out. So any idea how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question completely, but I'd like to show you [another way](https://github.com/rackspace/pyrax/blob/master/docs/cloud_servers.md#ssh-key-authentication) to put your SSH keys on your servers, in automation using the Rackspace API. If, for instance, you're using [pyrax](https://github.com/rackspace/pyrax/blob/master/docs/cloud_servers.md):

```
import pyrax
import os

pyrax.set_setting("identity_type", "rackspace")
pyrax.set_setting("username", USER_NAME) # User name
pyrax.set_setting("api_key", API_KEY) # Located in the control panel in settings

# Could also use a credential file
# pyrax.set_credential_file(os.path.expanduser("~/.rackspace_cloud_credentials"))

# Put your SSH key on the Rackspace cloud
pubkey = open("my_priv_key").read()
cs.keypairs.create("testkey", pubkey)

# For demo purposes, grab a sample image, server type (flavor in OpenStack parlance)
flavor_512 = [flavor for flavor in cs.flavors.list() if flavor.ram == 512][0]
ubu_image = [img for img in cs.images.list() if "Ubuntu 12.04" in img.name][0]

# Now we can create the server and assign an ssh key
server = cs.servers.create("ubbie", ubu_image.id, flavor_512.id,
        key_name="testkey")
```

Your API Key is located in Settings and Contacts within the Cloud Control panel, underneath the security question:

[image: API Key]

Once the server is built, you should be able to grab the ip address

```
server = cs.servers.get(server.id)
ip = server.accessIPv4
```

Then simply ssh as root using the key you specified.

```
ssh -i my_priv_key root@<ip>
```

If Python isn't your preferred language, there are other options. You can also make direct requests/use curl if that's your thing, as this is part of the [Rackspace API](http://docs.rackspace.com/servers/api/v2/cs-devguide/content/ServersKeyPairs-d1e2545.html) and [OpenStack/nova proper](http://docs.openstack.org/essex/openstack-compute/starter/content/Creation_of_Key_Pairs-d1e1848.html).

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the permissions & time settings on the server.
Also, have u intentionally removed the username from the post.

Try doing ssh with -v option. This will give more output for debugging.

Comment: also make sure you have right selinux context in case you're using it. Run the command:-     restorecon -r -vv /home/user/.ssh

Comment: I checked the permissions.They are fine. I also added my public key in root's ssh directory of the server. Now when I try ssh with -i and private key....It connects without any password prompts...so any idea how to tackle this for normal users..?

Comment: can you paste here the output of ssh -v user@server

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I have found to setup SSH keys on a remote server is to use the ssh-copy-id command.

http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-copy-id

Comment: I used ssh-copy-id to copy ssh keys to root's ssh directory and it worked fine but when I tried for users(at the server) via "ssh-copy-id user@IP", It asked for user's password even though the user didn't have any.